# I have a stoneware casserole dish with weird lines that look like cracks, but the dish doesn't feel any different

Tags: stoneware

I received a stoneware set of three mixing bowls and two casserole dishes. The larger casserole dish doesn't have these lines, but they started to appear in the smaller one after a few uses. I've read that the lines were likely there when the dish was made. It's too late now, but for future knowledge, would there be any way to return something like this?

[image: casserole dish stoneware]

Comment: You need to look up the customer services laws for your territory. In the UK, you could send that back as a factory defect up to 6 months after you bought it.

Comment: Hey thanks so much for your reply! Even though you're in the UK, it at least points me in a direction. Thanks again.